# How many rational numbers $\dfrac{p}{q}$ can be there between 0 and 1 with $q\le m$? Might any one of them equal a?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality, continuity

Let a be an irrational number with $0<a<1$.Given $\epsilon>0$,we seek a $\delta$ such that $|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. There exist a positive integer $m$ such that $\dfrac{1}{m}<\epsilon$. How many rational numbers $\dfrac{p}{q}$ can be there between 0 and 1 with $q\le m$? Might any one of them equal a?

Disclaimer: My answer might sound Super Genius.

There are infinite rational number $\dfrac{p}{q}$ between 0 and 1 but for $q\le m$? I don't know. None of them equal a because a is irrational.

But book says: For each $q$, there are $q$ possible values for $p$ and so not more than $1+2+3+...+m=\dfrac{m(m+1)}{2}$ rational numbers between 0 and 1 with denominator $\le m$.

Comment: What exactly is the difficulty you have in understanding what the book says?

Comment: Which part of what the book says is unclear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can easily list all the rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ with denominator at most $q$, although some numbers are repeated:
$$\frac12,\\
\frac13, \frac23,\\
\frac14, \frac24, \frac34,\\
\vdots\\
\frac1m,\ldots,\frac{m-1}m$$
There is $1$ number in the first line, $2$ in the second and so on down to $m-1$ in the last, and summing these we get $m(m-1)/2$. Of course this is an overestimate since e.g. $\frac12=\frac24$ appears in both the first and third lines.

Answer (score 0):

What is the number of elements of the following set:

$$ M_m:=\{(p,q) \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N: p \le q \le m\} ?$$